Is there a way to keep the selection after changing the preprocessing?
I am working with hyperspectral images (.hdr or .tab) in the ORANGE DATA MINING v3.37 software. For the images, I select a region, do preprocessing and select the ROIs. I want to know if there is any way that I change the preprocessing steps (not deleting the widget) and not lose the ROI selection I do after. I've tried different things but I always end up losing them.
Thank you in advance!
